# Using the Java File Leak Detector with java.nio.file.Files methods

Tags: java

I have troubles with some files remaining occasionally open, even though there are no exceptions visible in my server. This leads after some days to a "too many open files" IOException.
I can see the open files with the `lsof` command.

So I tried the use Kohsuke's [File Leak Detector](https://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/), but unfortunately it does not instrument the class `sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl` used by the `java.nio.file.Files.copy(InputStream, Path, CopyOption...)` and `java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Path, OpenOption...)` methods.

I.e. if you run the following code and attach the file leak detector as javaagent to the JVM, you do not see any file accesses to the test.txt file:

```
Path tmpDir = Files.createTempDirectory("tmpdir");
Path tmpFile = tmpDir.resolve("test.txt");

Files.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream("file content".getBytes()), tmpFile);  // not detected by the file leak detector
Files.newInputStream(path); // also not detected
```

**Edit (27.03.2020):**
The above code is only for demonstration purposes to show, which file handling events are not detected by the File Leak Detector. In our real scenario, we are passing the InputStream as `DataHandler` back to the CXF Framework to return the file's content as MTOM to the client. In almost all cases the file handles get closed correctly, however in come rare cases the file handle stays open and there are no exceptions visible.

Is there any other tool available that helps me to detected files that do not get closed?
I suspect that the reason lies somewhere outside my java code (e.g. in the OS or the NFS protocol), nevertheless, I hope to gain some insights where the file handles get normally closed inside my web server.

Comment: `Files.copy()` with a `ByteArrayInputStream` will not leave an open file. `Files.newInputStream(path);` definitely will, since you're opening a file and never using the returned stream object.

Comment: Are the open files all temp files? Doesn't the file name and/or content give a clue to what the purpose of the file is, i.e. a hint to where in the code that file might have been opened?

Comment: @Andreas The above code was only for demonstration purposes. In practice we are not using temp folders and we pass the InputStream up to the CXF Framework to send the data as WebService Response (MTOM) to the client.In nearly all cases, the InputStream gets closed correctly. However, some remain for unknown reasons open.

Comment: When you *"pass the InputStream up to the CXF Framework"*, does the API you're using to do that specifically say that it'll take over responsibility for closing the input stream? If it doesn't then closing the stream is your responsibility. Perhaps the GC Finalizer is closing most of the streams for you, obscuring that your resource leaks are a lot worse than you think.

Comment: Resource leaks are really easy to fix. You just have to check every site where they are allocated.

Comment: @Andreas Our WebService returns a `javax.activation.DataHandler` that is annotated with `@XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")` in a web service with the `@MTOM(enabled = true)` annotation. It is CXF's job to close the InputStream provided by the DataHandler. I cannot imagine that CXF doesn't do that correctly as Stackoverflow would be full of messages regarding that topic....